# I tried $arch -x86_64 zsh and receive arch: posix_spawnp: zsh: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: macos, zsh

```
~ arch -x86_64 zsh
arch: posix_spawnp: zsh: Bad CPU type in executable
~
```

Rosseta of course installed. I tried everything and Googled everything. What should I do?

Comment: "Tried everything" doesn't give us any insights about what you already tried. Can you please list the things you've tried, and the result you got? Also, please copy/paste Terminal output as text and format as code, not everybody is able to see what is in a picture.

Comment: Also, can you run `type zsh` and then `file /path/to/zsh` using the path the first command showed? And then copy/paste commands and output into the question as well?